# Show that $f$ is homotopic to a constant function

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a compact manifold with $\dim(X)<n$ and $f:X \rightarrow S^n$ be a smooth function, show that $f$ is homotopic to a constant function.

I try to use the fact that $S^n$ is simply connected and and trying to proceed by contradiction but I am not sure how to move through the homotopy between $X$ and $S^n$ maybe i can using something like the sards theorem.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: This does not follow from the fact that $S^n$ is simply connected. Use Sard's lemma to show that $f$ cannot be surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sard's Lemma, the set of regular values of $f$ is dense in $S^n$.
Since $\dim X < \dim \Bbb S^n$, no value $f(x)$ with $x\in X$ is regular, and hence, $\Bbb S^n \setminus f(X)$ is dense.
It is in particular non-empty.

Without loss of generality, assume that the north pole $N$ is not in $f(X)$.
Let $\varphi \colon \Bbb S^n\setminus \{N\} \to \Bbb R^n$ be the stereographic projection from the north pole.
The map
$$
H(t,x) = \varphi^{-1}\left(t \varphi( f(x))\right)
$$
is then an homotopy from the constant map $H(0,\cdot)\equiv S$ (the south pole) and $H(1,\cdot)=f$.

Answer (score 2):

By the [Cellular approximation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem) we can deform $f$ to a cellular function. This map can't be surjective, because then it will be an "identification".

But $S^n\setminus \{pt \}\cong \Bbb R^n$.

---

**Edit**

After the comment by @Andreas Cap, this can certainly be improved.

A cellular map maps $n$-skeleta into $n$-skeleta.
The $n$-sphere has a decomposition as a $0$-cell and an $n$-cell.  But the $m$-skeleton of $S^n$ consists in just the base point. Thus the map is constant.

Comment: How do you guarantee that the cellular map is one-one?

Comment: You're right I don't.     But,  it can't be surjective because if so there's a theorem that it's an identification. Let me try to find a reference and correct.

Comment: There is a simpler direct argument: You can use a CW decomposition of $S^n$  that has just a $0$-cell and an $n$-cell. Then the $n-1$-skeleton of $S^n$ consists of just one point and for $dim(X)<n$ any cellular map $X\to S^n$ is automatically constant.

Comment: @AndreasCap that *is* better